# finding the closest XY coordinates in a large dataframe to reference coordinates in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, math, data-manipulation

i have a dataset with 1000's of rows in a dataframe with an ID. the sample dataframe is as follows

```
df1 <- data.frame(X = c(7.48, 7.82, 8.15, 8.47, 8.80, 9.20, 9.51, 9.83, 10.13, 10.59, 7.59, 8.06, 
8.39, 8.87, 9.26, 9.64, 10.09, 10.48, 10.88, 11.45), 
              Y = c(49.16, 48.78, 48.40, 48.03, 47.65, 47.24, 46.87, 46.51, 46.15, 45.73, 48.70, 
48.18, 47.72, 47.20, 46.71, 46.23, 45.72, 45.24, 44.77, 44.23), 
              ID = c("B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1_2", 
"B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2"), 
              TI = c(191.31, 191.35, 191.39, 191.44, 191.48, 191.52, 191.56, 191.60, 191.64, 191.69, 
1349.93, 1349.97, 1350.01, 1350.05, 1350.09, 1350.14, 1350.18, 1350.22, 1350.26, 1350.30))
```

in the 'df1' dataframe, i would like to subset the rows in each ID based on the closest distance between the coordinates in another dataframe. the reference dataframe sample is as follows

```
df2 <- data.frame(X = c(7.62,  8.25,  8.95,  9.71,  10.23), 
              Y = c(49.06,  48.30,  47.55,  46.77,  46.25))
```

the distance between each coordinate in 'df1' dataframe and 'df2' dataframe is calculated to find the closest coordinate with respect to 'df2' dataframe. the test data calculation is calculated in excel and presented in the picture as shown in below

[image]

the expected desired output is as follows

[image]

I tried the following code....

```
df1 <- data.frame(X = c(7.48, 7.82, 8.15, 8.47, 8.80, 9.20, 9.51, 9.83, 10.13, 10.59, 7.59, 8.06, 
8.39, 8.87, 9.26, 9.64, 10.09, 10.48, 10.88, 11.45), 
              Y = c(49.16, 48.78, 48.40, 48.03, 47.65, 47.24, 46.87, 46.51, 46.15, 45.73, 48.70, 
48.18, 47.72, 47.20, 46.71, 46.23, 45.72, 45.24, 44.77, 44.23), 
              ID = c("B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1_2", 
"B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2"), 
              TI = c(191.31, 191.35, 191.39, 191.44, 191.48, 191.52, 191.56, 191.60, 191.64, 191.69, 
1349.93, 1349.97, 1350.01, 1350.05, 1350.09, 1350.14, 1350.18, 1350.22, 1350.26, 1350.30))

df2 <- data.frame(X = c(7.62,  8.25,  8.95,  9.71,  10.23), 
              Y = c(49.06,  48.30,  47.55,  46.77,  46.25))
library(data.table)
df1=as.data.table(df1)
a <- do.call(rbind,
    apply(df2,1,function(i){
      df1[,d:=(df1$X-i[1])^2+(df1$Y-i[2])^2]
      df1[df1[,.I[d==min(d)],by=ID]$V1]
    })

library(dplyr)
sorted <- a %>% arrange(ID,TI)
)
```

I am looking for the code to get the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step-1

we can calculate the distances between each df1 and df2 using the following code

```
df1 <- data.frame(X = c(7.48, 7.82, 8.15, 8.47, 8.80, 9.20, 9.51, 9.83, 10.13, 10.59, 7.59, 8.06, 8.39, 8.87, 9.26, 9.64, 10.09, 10.48, 10.88, 11.45), 
              Y = c(49.16, 48.78, 48.40, 48.03, 47.65, 47.24, 46.87, 46.51, 46.15, 45.73, 48.70, 48.18, 47.72, 47.20, 46.71, 46.23, 45.72, 45.24, 44.77, 44.23), 
              ID = c("B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2"), 
              TI = c(191.31, 191.35, 191.39, 191.44, 191.48, 191.52, 191.56, 191.60, 191.64, 191.69, 1349.93, 1349.97, 1350.01, 1350.05, 1350.09, 1350.14, 1350.18, 1350.22, 1350.26, 1350.30))

df2 <- data.frame(X = c(7.62,  8.25,  8.95,  9.71,  10.23), 
              Y = c(49.06,  48.30,  47.55,  46.77,  46.25))


Azimuth <- data.frame(0)
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(df1)){
Azimuth[j,i] = sqrt((df2[i,1]-df1[j,1])^2+(df2[i,2]-df1[j,2])^2)
}}
```

then we can combine df1 data frame and Azimuth using the following code

```
df1 <- data.frame(df1,Azimuth)
```

step-2

[to get the desired output, we got the answer from the "akrun"]
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65345208/how-to-subset-rows-in-specific-columns-based-on-minimum-values-in-individual-col[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65345208/how-to-subset-rows-in-specific-columns-based-on-minimum-values-in-individual-col%5B1%5D)

the code is as follows

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
nm1 <- names(df1)[5:6]
map_dfr(nm1, ~ df1 %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     slice_min(!! rlang::sym(.x))) %>% 
 ungroup %>%
 mutate(d = select(., all_of(nm1)) %>% reduce(pmin))
```