# how to subset rows in specific columns based on minimum values in individual columns in a dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

we have a data frame that has 1000's of rows with multiple columns. the sample data frame is presented below

```
df1 <- data.frame(X = c(7.48, 7.82, 8.15, 8.47, 8.80, 9.20, 9.51, 9.83, 10.13, 10.59, 7.59, 8.06, 8.39, 8.87, 9.26, 9.64, 10.09, 10.48, 10.88, 11.45), 
              Y = c(49.16, 48.78, 48.40, 48.03, 47.65, 47.24, 46.87, 46.51, 46.15, 45.73, 48.70, 48.18, 47.72, 47.20, 46.71, 46.23, 45.72, 45.24, 44.77, 44.23), 
              ID = c("B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2", "B_1_2"), 
              TI = c(191.31, 191.35, 191.39, 191.44, 191.48, 191.52, 191.56, 191.60, 191.64, 191.69, 1349.93, 1349.97, 1350.01, 1350.05, 1350.09, 1350.14, 1350.18, 1350.22, 1350.26, 1350.30),
              X0 = c(0.172, 0.344,0.846,1.335,1.838,2.410,2.89,3.37,3.842,4.46,0.361,0.983,1.545,2.241,2.86,3.47,4.15,4.77,5.388,6.164),
              V2 = c(1.154,0.644,0.141,0.348,0.851,1.423,1.9059,2.3875,2.856,3.475,0.771,0.224,0.596,1.262,1.883,2.493,3.168,3.786,4.402,5.177))
```

in the dataframe 'df1' we would like to subset rows by ID wise in the columns 1:4 based on minimum values in the 5th column and 6th column respectively.

for instance, in the data frame 'df1', ID "B_1" in 'X0' column, 0.172 is the minimum value and 0.140 is the minimum value in 'V2'th column for the same ID. so we would like to subset 1st row and 3rd row from column 1:4 along with their corresponding X0th and V2th value of the df1 data frame as shown in the below figure. likewise for the ID "B_1_2" also. like variables 'X0', 'V2' variables we have more than 20 variables in my dataset.

[image]

the expected output is shown in the below figure

[image]

to get the desired output I tried the code as presented below

```
library(data.table)
df1=as.data.table(df1)
a <- do.call(rbind,
    apply(df1,1,function(i){
     df1[df1[,.I[(X0)==min(X0)],by=ID]$V1]
    })
)
```

there are issues in the above code.
i am looking for the code to get the desired output

Comment: What exactly is the issue with your code?

Comment: @akrun the d variable is nothing but the minimum values in each column with respect to rows

Comment: i didn't understand your last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` to loop over the columns 'X0', 'V2', grouped by 'ID', slice the rows where the value is `min` for that looped column, bind them together (`_dfr`) and create the 'd' column with `pmin` of those columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
nm1 <- names(df1)[5:6]
map_dfr(nm1, ~ df1 %>%
         group_by(ID) %>%
         slice_min(!! rlang::sym(.x))) %>% 
     ungroup %>%
     mutate(d = select(., all_of(nm1)) %>% reduce(pmin))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#      X     Y ID       TI    X0    V2     d
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  8.47  48.0 B_1    191. 0.134 0.348 0.134
#2  7.59  48.7 B_1_2 1350. 0.361 0.771 0.361
#3  8.15  48.4 B_1    191. 0.846 0.141 0.141
#4  8.06  48.2 B_1_2 1350. 0.983 0.224 0.224
```

Comment: in the sample data, we have only 2 variables.... but in the dataset, we have more than 20 variables. in such a case it is laborious to mention "which.min(V2)" for each variable.

Comment: and moreover, only the minimum values of that particular column is required. for instance, in 'X0' column, 0.172 is the minimum value for the ID 'B_1', thus only 1:4 columns of the 1st row with 0.172 are to be subsetted, the other values in the column V2, V3, V4, and V5 are not required. similarly, for the V2 column of ID 'B_1', 0.141 is the minimum value thus, 1:4 columns of 3rd row and the minimum value of V2th column (0.141) is to be subsetted, the other values in X0, V3, V4, and V5 are not required

Comment: @Kumar What I understand is that you want the whole row where 'V2' is `min` and `X0` is `min`.  Otherwise, it would be just two row output because there are only tow unique ID

Comment: the desired output is clearly shown in the figure. in the figure, I have shown only for X0 and V2 columns. i want the whole row from column 1 to 4 along with their minimum values in columns- X0, V2, V3, V4, and V5

Comment: @Kumar That is what I get.  But your comment says that you don't want some columns

Comment: when i ran your code, i am not getting the desired output as shown in the figure. please see the desired output figure 'd' column. it is nothing but the minimum values in column X0 and V2. i want to combine all the minimum values in column X0, V2, V3,V4 and V5 into one column 'd' as shown in figure

Comment: @Kumar In that case, what will be the value of 'X'  and 'Y' i.e. which row of 'X' and 'Y' should be selected

Comment: @Kumar THe d value of `0.172` is not correct

Comment: for the column 'X0', 0.172 is the minimum value for ID 'B_1'. so, 0.172 value is in the first row  and I would like to subset that row from columns 'X', 'Y', 'ID' and 'TI' and 0.172 which is in the column X0.

Comment: @Kumar Based on the input example, it would be `0.134`

Comment: @Kumar IN your input example , it is showed `0.134` while in the excel image it is `1.134`  please check

Comment: ya 1.335 is correct and in the code ..... is there a way to avoid using column names in "c("X0", "V2")"  because in the actual dataset, we have more than 20 columns to avoid the laborious task?! or can we use column numbers instead

Comment: @Kumar You can just subset column names with `names(df1)[5:6]` and pass that in `map` (assuming those columns are in sequence in the data)

Comment: where to add names(df1)[5:6]  in " mutate(d = pmin(X0, V2, V3, V4, V5))"..... i have passed in map?

Comment: thanks for the code and update..... the code is working